# Starting forever running background jobs with Django Celery?

Tags: django-celery

I am using Django Framework to accept Http Request, where user can start a service or Stop service etc.

When user issues a start service command, I would like to start job in background which will keep running until user stops it. is it possible to achieve same with celery?

I tried to achieve it using celery but since its a blocking job, worker won't be able to accept next job. Hence seems like its not a scalable approach. Am i missing something? Or How can i achieve this?